# Recursively retrieving all possible combinations from an Array of Groups in order. Array size and groups size are 1-X where X is not a large number

Tags: php, sql, arrays, recursion, permutation

I need to recursively get all permutations in order of an array of groups.

So the Array would look something like: ([8,2], [5,7,9], [3,2])

The program would put together a string that would look something like this (pipes are simply added for aesthetics):

8, 5, 3 |
8, 5, 2 |
8, 7, 3 |
8, 7, 2 |
8, 9, 3 |
8, 9, 2 |
2, 5, 3 |
2, 5, 2 |
etc....

The output would end upon the last combination using all 3 groups. Once again, the number of groups can change and the number of elements within each group can change. I got partway there with the following method in php. (Yes, I am trying to build a complex sql view on the fly, but ignore the extraneous stuff. ViewGroups is the array of groups and viewstring is the output I need at the end. All the rest fits within the described parameters above. Please ignore the commented out lines of code. I am working on this as I ask the question!). :

```
   private function recSelect(array $viewGroups, string $viewString)
{
    if (count($viewGroups) == 0) {
        return " AND " . $this->buildWhere();
    } elseif (count($viewGroups) == $this->vgCount) {
        foreach ($viewGroups[0] as $el) {
            $viewString .= "Select * from patients where " . $el->getWhereClause();
            $viewString .= $this->recSelect(array_slice($viewGroups, 1), $viewString) . ' UNION ';
            //return $this->recSelect(array_slice($viewGroups, 1), $viewString) . ' UNION ';
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($viewGroups[0] as $el) {
            return " AND " . $el->getWhereClause() . $this->recSelect(array_slice($viewGroups, 1), $viewString);;
            //$viewString .= $this->recSelect(array_slice($viewGroups, 1), $viewString);
            //return;
            //return $this->recSelect(array_slice($viewGroups, 1), $viewString);
        }
    }
    return $viewString;
}
```

Any and all suggestions are appreciated!!

Comment: It might be easier to make an array of all the combinations and then iterate over it (or you might even be able to be smart with `implode` e.g. https://3v4l.org/Zg7Xa

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/4688876) might be what you're looking for - [tested](https://3v4l.org/qVvRp) on your sample data

Comment: Nick - Your answer worked with the data given but failed on my actual data. (Every other array was an object not an array). Don't know why you guys provided answers as comments, but  jibsteroos was perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second comment from jibsteroos  answered this question perfectly. Not sure why you guys posted your potential answers as comments. But I am new to this stuff.